# How to manually add a skeleton in Qt3d?

Tags: qt, qt3d

In Qt, I added a Mesh using `QSceneLoader`, but I wanted to rig the mesh manually in QT using the classes from Qt3D: `QJoint, QSkeleton, and QArmature`. I have not seen a lot of documentation on creating a skeleton that's applied to a mesh through C++ alone.

Even without C++, I found you can give an armature value in QML, but the file needs to be a `.gltf`. What I want to do is use C++ directly to make a skeleton so the programming-side has full control of the bone hierarchy.

`QSkeleton` gives one the abilitiy to add joints and child joints, but how are these joints then applied to the mesh? If there's any examples on this that would also be a great help.

Here's what I've tried:

```
Qt3DCore::QSkeleton* skeleton = new Qt3DCore::QSkeleton();
Qt3DCore::QJoint* joint = new Qt3DCore::QJoint();
joint->setTranslation(entityTransform->translation());
skeleton->setRootJoint(joint);
Qt3DCore::QArmature* a = new Qt3DCore::QArmature();
a->setSkeleton(skeleton);
entity->addComponent(a);
```

I also have an update function where I change the joint's translation/rotation and re-apply the skeleton to the armature, but it does nothing, so I don't know if the joint/armature has been applied properly to the mesh.

Comment: You also have to set the skeleton on the armature. But other than that it looks like you have to add an attribute to the vertices of your model which captures the index of the joint it is influenced by, as well as the weight of the joint. You then need a custom shader that takes the joints into account. Maybe [this](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/tree/5.11/tests/manual/skinned-mesh) test from the tests folder of the Qt3D git repository can help you.

Comment: oh yes, I did set the skeleton, but I haven't done any GLSL. I was trying to avoid that if I could. I thought there might be something similar to a Game Engine where you can load a mesh/skeleton and update joints through code.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to this question. Did you end up using QSkeleton, etc? Qt3D developers, a working example would be really helpful.